# Why won't Ubuntu 11.10 fully boot?

Tags: boot, helpfile

I get stuck on boot-up and need help. I get an error message that says:

> 103.795829 drm:drm_crtc_helper_set_config. ERROR failed to set mode on crtc:6.

Can anyone help me fix this?

Comment: Assume it is a hardware issue like graphic card, provide your graphic card information might useful.

Answer (score 1):

My Googlefu leads me to believe that you have an nvidia graphics chip and you are using the default nouveau graphics drivers.

Also, these issues can sometimes be overcome by editing your Grub boot option and adding *nomodeset*

Once you reach to the desktop I would open the Additional Drivers window and activate the *nvidia-current* driver.

I've linked to an answer I've previously given showing you how to add boot options such as *nomodeset*

---

Linked Question:

1. [How do I set 'nomodeset' after I've already installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-to-set-nomodeset-for-installation/38834#38834)